# Ubuntu 14.04: setting environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, android-studio

I need set environment variables for Android Studio project EVERY TIME when reboot or close terminal. (Ubuntu 14.04) For setting variables I use:

```
export KEYSTORE_NAME=/home/anna/Documents/keys/NAME.keystore 
export KEYSTORE_NAME_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
export KEY_NAME_ALIAS=NAME
export KEY_NAME_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

How can I set there variables forever?

Answer (score 7):

Add the exports to your `~/.profile`, that way they are loaded on every login.

Relevant: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables